# Find the value of a date subinterval given a list of date intervals with Python

Tags: python, algorithm

Say I have a dataset consisting of a bunch of dateranges (a start date and an end date) and a value for each daterange. For example, My data may look like the following

```
Start         End           Value
2005-01-01    2005-01-31    6.54
2005-02-01    2005-02-28    5.55
2005-03-01    2005-03-31    3.67
2005-04-01    2005-04-30    2.91
```

This will be stored in Python using as a list of tuples:

```
mydata = [(datetime.date(2005, 1, 1), datetime.date(2005, 1, 31), 6.54), 
          (datetime.date(2005, 2, 1), datetime.date(2005, 2, 28), 5.55),
          (datetime.date(2005, 3, 1), datetime.date(2005, 3, 31), 3.67),
          (datetime.date(2005, 4, 1), datetime.date(2005, 4, 30), 2.91)]
```

I want a function that can take any date interval as an input and output the sum of the values. For example, if my input is `[datetime.date(2005, 2, 1), datetime.date(2005, 3, 31)]` then my output would be 9.22 (equal to 5.55 + 3.67).

However, if my input is `[datetime.date(2005, 2, 1), datetime.date(2005, 3, 15)]` then my output would be `None` since I wouldn't have a match.

Comment: What have you tried? A linear algorithm should be really easy to implement. (But of course, a binary search would be better.)

Comment: I built a really horrible brute force algorithm that works but its way too slow. Haven't tried binary search because I don't know where to begin.

Comment: Also, I can't do linear because what if I have another item in data that overlaps another item. Eg. what if I also had (2005-02-01, 2005-02-15, 2.22) in my data. Then I couldn't build a linked list.

Comment: What would it mean to have overlapping dates? I'm a little bit confused about the exact requirements now. I expected that a query `(start, end)` is valid if `start` matches one of your start dates and `end` matches one of your end dates. In that case, I thought that your value would simply be the sum of all intervals starting after `start` and before `end`. Is it more complicated than that? Can you elaborate?

Comment: what does the "value" mean? Depending on its relation to the dates you could try to just compute the result without looking up in the datastructure.

Answer (score 1):

One potential solution would be to store all of the dates (both start and end types) into a sorted list. There would be another data structure (probably a dictionary) that maintains the mappings between the start and end dates along with the value.

Your search would consist of getting all the values in the sorted list within the range specified, which can be efficiently done with binary search. For each start/end date in the returend values, the corresponding start/end date must also be found. If a start date is found without an end date, or an end date is found without a start date, then that daterange does not fall within the boundaries of your search and should not be included in your results. This step could be implemented efficiently with a dictionary.

For that second step, I would use a bimap so looking up a start/end date from a given one is easy. When processing the dates found with the binary search, you can look up the element you expect to find in the list and maintain an expected list. If that element is found later on in the search, remove it from the expected list.

Answer (score 0):

look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search search where dates are nodes and value are cost edge.